# How to skip values that have NULL values in a TSQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this rather complex query:

```
SELECT distinct 
    v.KodQ, v.DodPeriodika, 
    v.GodGP, v.Periodika as Period, 
    k.Oblast, k.KratokNazivSI, 
    k.NazivSI, k.Periodika, 
    v.rKod, r.Naziv, 
    v.rDatum,
    v.IT, v.Primerok, v.BrojIE, 
    CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATETIME, v.RefPeriodOd), 103) as RefPeriodOd,
    CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATETIME, v.RefPeriodDo), 103) as RefPeriodDo


    FROM GP.dbo.MyTable1 AS v 

    INNER JOIN GP.dbo.MyTable2 as k 
    ON k.KodSI = v.KodQ AND k.DodObr = v.DodPeriodika

    INNER JOIN GP.dbo.MyTable3 AS r 
    ON r.rKod = v.rKod

    WHERE v.GodGP = GodGP and CHARINDEX('-', RefPeriodDo, 0) != 0
```

I need to convert **v.RefPeriodOd** and **v.RefPeriodDo** from this format **'31-Dec-2017'** to this format **'31/12/2017'**.

Yes I know saving DateTime as string(varchar) is bad idea, but the application is now in use so I cannot really do QA at the moment and refactor my table.

I am using this statement:

```
CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATETIME, v.RefPeriodDo), 103) as RefPeriodDo
```

But the problem is, **v.RefPeriodOd** and **v.RefPeriodDo** can have a NULL values and also values in the format: **'31/12/2017'**

If I remove this condition:

```
CHARINDEX('-', RefPeriodDo, 0) != 0
```

I get this error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

How can I add some conditions in the query?

Does IF statement exists in `TSQL`?

Comment: You should include this in your tags next time too

Comment: Handling `null` is the easy part. your real problem is to handle data like `31-02-2018` or `30-0y-2017`, that you can't protect from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATETIME, v.RefPeriodOd), 103) as RefPeriodOd
```

for

```
CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', RefPeriodDo, 0) != 0 
    THEN CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATETIME, v.RefPeriodOd), 103) 
END as RefPeriodOd
```

And remove the filter in the `WHERE`.

"IFs" are expressed with the `CASE` clause if inside `SELECT` statements, and the most common syntax is the following:

```
CASE
    WHEN 1stCondition THEN 1stValue
    WHEN 2ndCondition THEN 2ndValue
    ELSE DefaultValue -- Else is optional
END
```

Conditions are evaluated in order, and if no `ELSE` is issued, then `NULL` is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add to the `where` the following:

```
WHERE (v.RefPeriodOd is not null and v.RefPeriodOd <> '')
  AND (v.RefPeriodDo is not null and v.RefPeriodDo <> '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Note:

- You cannot put the condition in the `WHERE` clause.  The filtering is not necessarily before the expressions in the `SELECT`.
- You should always include a length for strings in SQL Server.

The right way to handle this is `try_convert()`:

```
TRY_CONVERT(varchar(255), TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, v.RefPeriodOd), 103) as RefPeriodOd,
TRY_CONVERT(varchar(255), TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, v.RefPeriodDo), 103) as RefPeriodDo
```

`TRY_CONVERT()` is available since SQL Server 2012.  Before that, you needed to use a `CASE` to avoid conversion errors.

In my opinion, the filter condition should be:

```
RefPeriodDo LIKE '%-%'
```

I think this is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Why use `varchar(255)` when `char(10)` is enough?

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . I always make the field big enough so I don't have to think about the length.

Comment: Also, isn't the `where` clause guaranteed to be evaluated before the `select` clause?

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . No.  The `WHERE` clause is guaranteed to be *parsed* before the `SELECT`.  Sort of.  I mean, the scoping rules are what you are really referring to, and that means that the components of the `WHERE` are taken into account before anything in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct 
    v.KodQ, v.DodPeriodika, 
    v.GodGP, v.Periodika as Period, 
    k.Oblast, k.KratokNazivSI, 
    k.NazivSI, k.Periodika, 
    v.rKod, r.Naziv, 
    v.rDatum,
    v.IT, v.Primerok, v.BrojIE, 
    CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATETIME, v.RefPeriodOd), 103) as RefPeriodOd,
    CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(DATETIME, v.RefPeriodDo), 103) as RefPeriodDo
FROM GP.dbo.MyTable1 AS v 
INNER JOIN GP.dbo.MyTable2 as k 
ON k.KodSI = v.KodQ AND k.DodObr = v.DodPeriodika
INNER JOIN GP.dbo.MyTable3 AS r 
ON r.rKod = v.rKod
WHERE v.GodGP = GodGP AND ISNULL(v.RefPeriodOd,'')<>'' AND ISNULL(v.RefPeriodDo,'')<>''
```

Filter the rows using `WHERE`:

```
WHERE v.GodGP = GodGP AND ISNULL(v.RefPeriodOd,'')<>'' AND ISNULL(v.RefPeriodDo,'')<>''
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this as try
Note the double use of 103

```
declare @D table (id int identity primary key, dt varchar(20));
insert into @D (dt) values (null), ('messy'), ('31-Dec-2017'), ('31/12/2017'), ('1/12/2017');
select d.dt 
     , TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, d.dt, 103) as dt103 
     , isnull(TRY_CONVERT(varchar(20), TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, d.dt, 103), 103), d.dt) dt103var
from @D d;

dt                   dt103                   dt103var
-------------------- ----------------------- --------------------
NULL                 NULL                    NULL
messy                NULL                    messy
31-Dec-2017          2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 31/12/2017
31/12/2017           2017-12-31 00:00:00.000 31/12/2017
1/12/2017            2017-12-01 00:00:00.000 01/12/2017
```